# defaultTracker is nil in Google Analytics for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up Google Analytics in my iOS app by following this guide [Google Analytics for iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift)
I have completed all the steps but when I run my app it crashes and says that my defaultTracker is nil. This is the following code in my ViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: nil)

    var builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
    tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])

}
```

In my AppDelegate I have this code that should initialize everything regarding the tracker:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(application: UIApplication) {
    // Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
    var configureError:NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    // Optional: configure GAI options.
    var gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
    gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose  // remove before app release
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance
Vatan

Answer (score 7):

I had same issue, fixed with adding default tracker initialization at `AppDelegate` `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method like below;

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    //...

    var gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
    gai.defaultTracker = gai.trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXX-X")
    //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need you set your `defaultTracker` to `gai` variable in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` after defining the `gai` variable.

Comment: How would I set it? I can't find any suitable method and it doesn't feel right to set it by defining the trackingnumber since it is already defined in the GoogleService-Info.plist file

Comment: Did you see my previous comment @Deepak

Comment: Can you double check that your GoogleService-Info.plist file is added to your target  i.e Select the GoogleService-Info.plist and  Under File Inspector check the tickmark for your target in Target Membership section.

Comment: Hi, yes tick mark is there. If I go to my app settings and the under Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, it is also listed there

Comment: I also have an Info.plist, do you think it can interfere anything?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be a problem.